# Text swatch not showing up

Tags: magento2

I've created a new text swatch "size2" with a three sizes (A, B and C), then I added a new configurable product to my catalog with the three variations, as you can see on the screenshot below.
[image: Backend configurable product with its three variations]

But only the title "size2" is showing up, without the newly configured sizes, as you can see on the picture below.
[image: Frontpage]

What's wrong in my configuration ?

I'm using Magento 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the product attribute (Store->Attributes->Product), I had to feel all columns in "Attribute Information" -> Properties -> "Manage Swatch".

Thanks to this post :
https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Text-swatch-not-showing-up/m-p/58698#M1841

Answer (score 0):

**You have to need change of core file other wise override to it**

Path : vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/OptionsVisual.php

```
public function getJsonConfig()
     * Parse swatch labels for template
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @param null $swatchStoreValue  //Remove
     * @return string                //Remove
     * @param null|array $swatchStoreValue  //Add
     * @return null|array                   //Add
     */
    protected function reformatSwatchLabels($swatchStoreValue = null)
    {
        if ($swatchStoreValue === null) {
            return;
        }
        $newSwatch = '';  // Remove
        $newSwatch = [];  //Add
        foreach ($swatchStoreValue as $key => $value) {
            if ($value[0] == '#') {
                $newSwatch[$key] = 'background: '.$value;
```